# Powershell Pull data from json, append to another file

Tags: json, windows, powershell, scripting

Trying to create a script (doesn't matter what language but using Powershell in this case) to do as the title says. Pulling data from my Anti-malware software and applying the blocked websites to the Windows blacklist. I been working on it but not the most experienced with PowerShell. Thank you all for assistance!

```
    #This is all of the files in the folder
    $FolderContents = Get-ChildItem "C:\ProgramData\Malwarebytes\MBAMService\MwacDetections" -Filter *.json

    #Loop to go through each file individually
    for ($jsonFile=0; $jsonFile -lt $FolderContents.Count; $jsonFile++) {

     #Get the content *attempt #1*
     $x = $jsonFile | ConvertFrom-Json

     #Get the content of the file *attempt #2*
     $jsonFileContents = Get-Content $FolderContents[$jsonFile] | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

     #Test append
     #Add-Content C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.txt *place file content variable here*
     #REAL APPEND
     #Add-Content C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts *place file content variable here*
    }
```

**~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ADDITIONAL PICTURES~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~**

**Error of Individual file and .json file example**

[image: Error of Individual file and .json file example]

**Scope/depth of data error & PowerShell version**

> [image: Scope/depth of data error & PowerShell version]

Comment: What's not working? Note you need appropriate permission to write to the Windows system folder.

Comment: Well I'm just stuck logically on what to do (weird huh considering the simplicity?). If I run the code right now, I'll get the error:
`Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\me\f2a011c6-0f69-11e8-98b4-f0761ce1dafe.json' because it does not exist.`

I understand it's because of setting proper variables to point at but after a few hours, I felt I was working on it too long and sought help lol.

Comment: So... does `C:\Users\me\f2a011c6-0f69-11e8-98b4-f0761ce1dafe.json` exist? The error seems pretty clear that it doesn't. Do you see it in File Explorer?

Comment: The File does exist, it's just not the correct path. The correct path should be `"C:\ProgramData\Malwarebytes\MBAMService\MwacDetections"` which is stored in the `$FolderContents` variable as shown above in line #2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your code. 
First of all I suggest to improve variable naming (see my proposal below). It makes your code better readable. Next, attempt #1 won't work as you pipe the index of the for loop to `ConvertFrom-Json` Cmdlet (i.e. `0 | ConvertFromJson`) instead of the content of the file. And last but not least the error you get when calling `Get-Content` Cmdlet occurrs because you pass a filename as path argument to the `Get-Content` Cmdlet instead of the full file path. `$FolderContents[$jsonFile]` just returns the file name and not the full path of the file. That's why `Get-Content` Cmdlet searches for the file in the current directory, which in your case is `C:\Users\me\`. To fix that either pipe the file to the `Get-Content` Cmdlet (`$jsonFileContents = $FolderContents[$jsonFile] | Get-Content | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json`) or pass full name of the file as path argument (`$jsonFileContents = Get-Content $FolderContents[$jsonFile].FullName | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json`).

```
# All json files contained in C:\ProgramData\Malwarebytes\MBAMService\MwacDetections
$pathToMwacDetections = "C:\ProgramData\Malwarebytes\MBAMService\MwacDetections";
$jsonFiles = Get-ChildItem $pathToMwacDetections -Filter *.json

# Loop to go through each file individually
for ($index=0; $index -lt $jsonFiles.Count; $index++) {

    # Get the content of the file and convert it 
    $jsonFileContent = Get-Content $jsonFiles[$index].FullName | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

    #Test append
    #Add-Content C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.txt *place file content variable here*
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help. Read your message, adjusted code, and now getting the error `ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive`. I don't understand this one so i'll need to look into it. Still stuck for now

Comment: You're welcome. Do you already know, if one of the file causes the problem? If not, try to execute the script code for just one file to check, if there is a problem with the code or with the content of one of the files.

Comment: So I went through each portion of the command on one individual file.

`$jsonFileContent = Get-Content "C:\ProgramData\Malwarebytes\MBAMService\MwacDetections\test.json" | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json`

I started just retrieving the data and checking the contents of the string each time. `Get-Content` outputs the data within the file exactly as is. I don't understand what `Out-String` does as it does not change anything when I include the pipe. However, after piping that into `ConvertFrom-Json`, the same error occurs. It points directly to the first line which is a String `1F86C1FCC8C904`

Comment: I'd also like to mention the file is JSON type. I didn't touch it at all. I had to shorten the string because of the char limit but it actually looks like `1F86C1FCC8C9045603BE522421DDC4C4CDC675A7066FD5052E29E0ED38693357`. The rest of the code is located in brackets. I'll attach a screen shot of it all as best as I can

Comment: The problem is, that according your screenshot the file does not contain valid json. The number on the first line is the problem...

Comment: @Simonhawk you could try to skip the first line when loading content as follows.  `$jsonFileContent = Get-Content $jsonFiles[$index].FullName | select -Skip 1 | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json`
If my answer correctly answered your question please rate it and mark it as answer.

Comment: Not solved yet. We brought the data from the file and transferred it into a PowerShell object. But now I'm having an issue viewing ALL the data. When I see `Get-Content` I can see everything exactly as the file portrays. However, after `CovertFrom-Json`,  we see a nice formated object. However, it doesn't get the data within arrays/lists (data within brackets `[ ]`) I've attached another image of the output and selected missing data. I figured an additional `-Depth 5` parameter would do since the default is 2 but I get an error. I also included my version of PowerShell. Thank you!

Comment: @Simonhawk if you pass the output of `Get-Content` to the console you will see exactly the same as in the file as `Get-Content` returns the content of the correpsonding file as string. However after conversion when passing the object to the console you will just see the properties of the root object as it's now an object. According your screenshot the data from JSON array is present in the PowerShell object. You won't see the whole hierarchy by just printing out `$jsonFileContent`. If you access for example `$jsonFileContent.threats` you will see the properties like `ruleID` and so on.

Comment: You're absolutely correct! I understood the stack from root and it's subdirectories, however I only knew how to reference the objects through `-depth`. Since I'm looking for the url the correct command was `$jsonFileContent.threats.mainTrace.websiteData.url`. Thank you very much. Now i just have to correctly append to the file and we're good :D